# Apache Beam - RabbitMq Read - fail ack message and exception raised

Tags: java, rabbitmq, apache-beam, apache-beam-io

I'm implementing a pipeline to read RabbitMq queue.

I'm having problems when I read it at unbound stream

it is saying that channel is already closed and ack is not sent to rabbitmq and message still on the queue:

```
WARNING: Failed to finalize Finalization{expiryTime=2020-11-21T19:33:14.909Z, callback=org.apache.beam.sdk.io.Read$UnboundedSourceAsSDFWrapperFn$$Lambda$378/0x00000001007ee440@4ae82af9} for completed bundle CommittedImmutableListBundle{PCollection=Read RabbitMQ queue/Read(RabbitMQSource)/ParDo(UnboundedSourceAsSDFWrapper)/ParMultiDo(UnboundedSourceAsSDFWrapper)/ProcessKeyedElements/SplittableParDoViaKeyedWorkItems.GBKIntoKeyedWorkItems.out [PCollection], key=org.apache.beam.repackaged.direct_java.runners.local.StructuralKey$CoderStructuralKey@3607f949, elements=[ValueInGlobalWindow{value=ComposedKeyedWorkItem{key=[-55, 41, -123, 97, 13, 104, 92, 61, 92, 122, -19, 112, -90, 16, 7, -97, 89, 107, -80, 12, 9, 120, 10, -97, 72, 114, -62, -105, 101, -34, 96, 48, 30, -96, 8, -19, 23, -115, -9, 87, 1, -58, -127, 70, -59, -24, -40, -111, -63, -119, 51, -108, 126, 64, -4, -120, -41, 9, 56, -63, -18, -18, -1, 17, -82, 90, -32, 110, 67, -12, -97, 10, -107, -110, 13, -74, -47, -113, 122, 27, 52, 46, -111, -118, -8, 118, -3, 20, 71, -109, 65, -87, -94, 107, 114, 116, -110, -126, -79, -123, -67, 18, -33, 70, -100, 9, -81, -65, -2, 98, 33, -122, -46, 23, -103, -70, 79, -23, 74, 9, 5, -9, 65, -33, -52, 5, 9, 101], elements=[], timers=[TimerData{timerId=1:1605986594072, timerFamilyId=, namespace=Window(org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.windowing.GlobalWindow@4958d651), timestamp=2020-11-21T19:23:14.072Z, outputTimestamp=2020-11-21T19:23:14.072Z, domain=PROCESSING_TIME}]}, pane=PaneInfo.NO_FIRING}], minimumTimestamp=-290308-12-21T19:59:05.225Z, synchronizedProcessingOutputWatermark=2020-11-21T19:23:14.757Z}
com.rabbitmq.client.AlreadyClosedException: channel is already closed due to clean channel shutdown; protocol method: #method<channel.close>(reply-code=200, reply-text=OK, class-id=0, method-id=0)
        at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.ensureIsOpen(AMQChannel.java:258)
        at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.transmit(AMQChannel.java:427)
        at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.transmit(AMQChannel.java:421)
        at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.recovery.RecoveryAwareChannelN.basicAck(RecoveryAwareChannelN.java:93)
        at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.recovery.AutorecoveringChannel.basicAck(AutorecoveringChannel.java:428)
        at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.rabbitmq.RabbitMqIO$RabbitMQCheckpointMark.finalizeCheckpoint(RabbitMqIO.java:433)
        at org.apache.beam.runners.direct.EvaluationContext.handleResult(EvaluationContext.java:195)
        at org.apache.beam.runners.direct.QuiescenceDriver$TimerIterableCompletionCallback.handleResult(QuiescenceDriver.java:287)
        at org.apache.beam.runners.direct.DirectTransformExecutor.finishBundle(DirectTransformExecutor.java:189)
        at org.apache.beam.runners.direct.DirectTransformExecutor.run(DirectTransformExecutor.java:126)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

---

**BUT**

if I include  withMaxNumRecords

I receive the message and ack is sent to rabbitmq queue

but it works as bound data

---

**CODE**

my code is like below:

```
    Pipeline p = Pipeline.create(options);

   PCollection<RabbitMqMessage> messages = p.apply("Read RabbitMQ queue",
        RabbitMqIO.read()
        .withUri("amqp://guest:guest@localhost:5672")
        .withQueue("queue")
        //.withMaxNumRecords(1)  // TRANFORM BOUND
        );
 
    PCollection<TableRow> rows = messages.apply("Transform Json to TableRow",
        ParDo.of(new DoFn<RabbitMqMessage, TableRow>() {

        @ProcessElement
        public void processElement(ProcessContext c) {

            ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
            String jsonInString = new String(c.element().getBody());
            LOG.info(jsonInString);
        }
  }));

  rows.apply(
      "Write to BigQuery",
      BigQueryIO.writeTableRows()
          .to("livelo-analytics-dev:cart_idle.cart_idle_process")
          .withCreateDisposition(BigQueryIO.Write.CreateDisposition.CREATE_NEVER)
          .withWriteDisposition(BigQueryIO.Write.WriteDisposition.WRITE_APPEND)
  );
```

Someone could help with this?

Answer (score 0):

I sent an email to apache dev thread and get an awesome answer from
Boyuan Zhang
that worked as a workaround for me

```
As a workaround, you can add --experiments=use_deprecated_read when launching your pipeline to bypass the sdf unbounded source wrapper here.
```

```
--experiments=use_deprecated_read
```

Put it as an argument on the command line and worked fine for me